# Remove selected items in the previous selections after cloning into a new dynamically generated dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net dropdown list and an asp.net button control. each time on  clicking the button, a new dropdownlist is supposed to get generated with all the values except for the one that are selected previously.

For example: If I selected 'a' from a list of values {a,b,c} and then clicked on the button, I am supposed to get a new dropdownlist with values {b,c}.

Although, I am able to clone the dropdownlist values, I have no idea how to filter the values by removing the selected ones.

**Edit**

Here is the **scenario**

- i start off with only 1 drop down list (that has 5 options) => 1,2,3,4,5 -> first options is selected by default.
- i select option 5 (in select list #2)
- I hit clone -> new list (#3) is added with ONLY options 2,3,4
- i select option 2 (in select list #3)
- I hit clone -> new list (#4) is created with options 3,4
- ..and so on.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCityName" runat="server" class="ddlClone" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="City" CssClass=""></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnClone" runat="server" Text="Clone" />
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=btnClone]").bind("click", function () {
            var index = $("#container select").length + 1;
            var ddl = $("[id$=ddlCityName]").clone();
            ddl.attr("id", "ddlCityName_" + index);
            ddl.attr("name", "ddlCityName_" + index);
            $("#container").append(ddl);
            $("#container").append("<br /><br />");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected value and remove it from the new select after clone, like this:

```
$(ddl).find("option[value='"+selVal+"']").remove();
```

Here is a jsFiddle with running example: https://jsfiddle.net/ntvo173q/

**I updated the jsFiddle to remove all previously selected items, just check out:**

What I did was get all selected values and remove from new select:

```
var ddl = $('#sel').clone();
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(ddl).find("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").remove();

    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ntvo173q/1/

Comment: Actually, I missed to inform that all the other dropdownlists generated must have the same attribute. For example:
if Dropdownlist1 has `<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Option 3</option>`

Comment: I didn't understand, isn't exactly this what the jsfiddle examples does?

Comment: Thank you @Ricardo, Although I was able to remove the selected but I was able to do it when I selected the First dropdown.I have edited the question for that matter.

Comment: I got, so for each new select, you want to add just options that wasn't select in previous selects, is it right?

Comment: I updated my response with a new jsFiddle that does what you need, please check out and let me know if answered your question.

Comment: This is working. But I just wanted to report that in the first two instances of creation i.e. the primary one and it's subsequent clone, I am not able to select the 'option 1'. is it supposed to happen?

Comment: I noticed this. It's like the option 1 is already selected, maybe you can add a first option link "select one" to solve this.

Comment: yeah! It would do. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnClone').click(function () {
    var original = $('select.ddlClone(0)');
    var allSelects = $('select.ddlClone');
    var clone = original.clone();

    $('option', clone).filter(function (i) {
        return allSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
    }).remove();

    $('#target').append(clone).append('<br /><br /><br />');
});
```